# Reparametrization Confusion

Tags: differential-geometry

Why is it true that if $\hat{\gamma}$ is a reparametrization of $\gamma$, then $\gamma$ is a reparametrization of $\hat{\gamma}$? I think I understand, but i'm not sure how to formally show this.

A $\textit{reparametrization}$ of a parametrized curve $\gamma: (\overline{\alpha}, \overline{\beta}) \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ if there is a smooth biective map $\phi: (\overline{\alpha}, \overline{\beta}) \to (\alpha, \beta)$ (reparametrization map) such that the inverse map is also smooth and $\hat{\gamma}(\hat{t}) = \gamma(\phi(t)) $ for all $\hat{t} \in (\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta})$.

Since $\phi^{-1}$ is also smooth and bijective, then we have $\gamma(t) = \hat{\gamma}(\phi^{-1}(t))$. But from here? I think I may have just "over-thinked" this.

Comment: Hint: substitute $\hat\gamma\leftrightarrow\gamma$ and $\phi^{-1}\leftrightarrow \psi$ in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare your last sentence with the definition. It is the same thing with $\phi^{-1}$ in place of $\phi$ and $\gamma$ and $\hat \gamma$ changed places.